# How do I add this left join to my query?

Tags: sql, join, pervasive

How do I add this...

```
LEFT JOIN quote_header ON 
    (job_header.job = '0' + LEFT(quote_header.user_5, 5))
```

To this...

```
SELECT 
    job_header.job,
    job_header.suffix,
    job_header.customer,
    job_header.description,
    job_header.comments_1,
    job_header.date_due,
    job_header.part,
    job_header.customer_po,
    job_header.date_closed,
    job_header.flag_hold,
    wo_user_flds.user_7,
    wo_user_flds.user_3,
    wo_user_flds.user_6,
    wo_user_flds.user_5,
    wo_user_flds.user_2

FROM job_header

LEFT JOIN wo_user_flds ON 
    (job_header.job = wo_user_flds.job) AND
    (job_header.suffix = wo_user_flds.suffix)

WHERE job_header.date_closed = '000000'

AND LENGTH(job_header.job) > '5';
```

I tried adding it immediately after the first left join, but it just crashes.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: What is the error you get or result?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it just hangs/crashes.

Comment: Could be a performance issue with the amount of data, lack of index etc ?

Comment: If you aren't getting an error then there is nothing syntactically incorrect with your code... you are just trying to perform a query that is too much for your database. Correcting this will take a better understanding of your tables and indices to create a plan which performs better.

Comment: @DanK I think you're right. The query without the second join runs almost instantly, but when I add the second one it takes like 4 minutes before it finally loads something. How do I handle this database struggle?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? Oracle, SQL Server? Each Database IDE should have performance plan monitoring that you can utilize to identify what operation is costly. If you can get a copy of your performance plan and the performance plan of your new query, you can post online here and someone will be able to assist you in rewriting your query or modifying your table to handle the data retrieval.

Comment: How big is your `quote_header` table ?

Comment: I'm using PSQL. I never had an issue with performance before, but I will definitely look into what you suggested about finding out what's bogging it down, so thank you for that. And I don't know what you mean by 'how big'? It has 46k rows and 200 columns. I'm gonna try to tweak my join conditions so it doesn't match so much.

Comment: You could try creating a couple of `views` that create the fields you're joining against, and use the views instead of directly using the tables?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Postgres so I won't be able to speak much to the details but I did find a site which speaks to Execution Plan which you may find helpful: http://www.postgresguide.com/performance/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using CONCAT instead of '0' + LEFT(......

OR

Maybe you could try putting quote_header into a temp table with the modified field and then joining to that...

```
SELECT CONCAT('0', LEFT(quote_header.user_5, 5)) as quoteHeaderUser_5, field2, field3 etc etc
INTO #tmpQH
FROM quote_header
```

So then you can have....

```
LEFT JOIN #tmpQH ON 
    (job_header.job = quoteHeaderUser_5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a couple of views...

**View1**

```
SELECT 
    ...

FROM job_header
WHERE job_header.date_closed = '000000'
AND LENGTH(job_header.job) > '5';
```

**View2**

```
SELECT 
    ...,
    '0' + LEFT(quote_header.user_5, 5) as 'FirstFiveOfUser5'
from quote_header
```

Then, you can join like this...

```
SELECT 
    job_header.job,
    job_header.suffix,
    job_header.customer,
    job_header.description,
    job_header.comments_1,
    job_header.date_due,
    job_header.part,
    job_header.customer_po,
    job_header.date_closed,
    job_header.flag_hold,
    wo_user_flds.user_7,
    wo_user_flds.user_3,
    wo_user_flds.user_6,
    wo_user_flds.user_5,
    wo_user_flds.user_2

FROM View1 as job_header

LEFT JOIN wo_user_flds ON 
    (job_header.job = wo_user_flds.job) AND
    (job_header.suffix = wo_user_flds.suffix)
LEFT JOIN View2 as quote_header ON 
    (job_header.job = quote_header.FirstFiveOfUser5)
```

This might help with the performance.